# How to know if show notification is enabled or disabled, if yes how to access it on Android 4.4+ devices?

Tags: android, notifications

Is there a way to find if the "Show notification" for app is enabled or disabled?
I have a requirement where I need to check and enable or disable notifications.

When you see the details of the any app, example in the link
http://www.trickyways.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/show-notifications-disabled.png
there is an option to disable notifications. Is there any function or method in Android with which I can extract this

I have seen articles that it can't be done for 4.0, wondering if there is any update for 4.4 and above

Comment: need more explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is for API Level >= 18.

You can include [`NotificationListenerService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html) in your project which allows you to listen to all the Notifications that are posted on the phone.

So whenever your application posts a new notification `NotificationListenerService` will get a callback. So, if you are posting a notification and `NotificationListenerService` is not getting a callback, it means user has blocked the notifications for your application.

Note that user needs to explicitly grant your application [Notification Access Permission](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE) in order for your application to access the notifications.